# Check for maximum in /scoreboard?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This command: ...

```
/scoreboard players remove @p[score_Gold_min=1] Gold 1
```

Says to remove a Gold from whoever has at least 1, but is there a way to reverse that to be like

```
/scoreboard players add @p[score_Gold_max=1] Gold 1
```

Or something like that... I just want to know if there is a maximum value to go with the minimum value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. `@p[score_Gold=1]` will match the nearest player with a Gold score less than or equal to 1.

Comment: I want less than or equal to

Comment: @DavidCole I'm an idiot, it returns players with a maximum, which is less than or equal. I just mixed up my words.